# Linear Algebra about planes

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you know that the plane passes through the origin and what would happen if it did not pass through the origin?

I am struggling with the interpretation of the same type of question:

Vectors: u=(0, 1, 1) and v=(1, 0, 1) in standard position.

Find an equation of the plane containing u and v.

I found the cross product (1 1 -1) but what then??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your result is correct, then both points are on the plane $\;x+y-z+d=0\;$ . Now just input both  given vectors in this to find that $\;d=0\;$ .

Comment: Is it possible to show me the steps of how did you get to the answer please?

Comment: @Matt In a plane $\;Ax+By+Cz=0\;$, the vector $\;(A,B,C)\;$ is perpendicular to the plane (this follows at once from the dot product definition), and thus you need a line through $\;A\;$ and in **that** direction to get a *perpendicular* line to the plane and throguh $\;A\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

If the origin is a point of the plane then its equation must be verified by $(0,0,0)$ so it must be a linear omogeneous equation:
$$
ax+by+cz=0
$$

where $(a,b,c)$ is a normal vector to the plane.

If the equation is not omogeneous, i.e.

$$
ax+by+cz+d=0 \quad d\ne 0
$$
then $(0,0,0)$ don't verify the equation, so the plane don't pass thorough the origin.